# Email from Google: Using a Google product name as the project in OAuth consent screen

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-developers-console

I received this message for the second time and i still dont understand why. Can someone help me?

> Action required: Critical problem with your Google Cloud/API project
> Youtube API (id: tonal-topic-123301)
>
> Dear Developer, We have recently
> detected that your Google Cloud/API project Youtube API (id:
> tonal-topic-123301) is using a Google product name as the project name
> shown to users on the OAuth consent screen, which violates the Google
> API Services: User Data Policy. You can fix the problem by revising
> the project name and other relevant content so that the OAuth consent
> screen shown to users accurately reflects the identity of your
> application.  To revise the project name visible to users, please take
> the following steps:
>
> Please review the Google API Services: User Data Policy, specifically
> the following section- "Do not make false or misleading statements
> about any entities that have allegedly authorized or managed your
> application. You must accurately represent the company, organization,
> or other authority that manages your application. Making false
> representations about client credentials to Google or Google users is
> grounds for suspension."
>
> Sign in to the Google Cloud Platform Console.
>
> Select your project.
>
> On the Home Page Dashboard, select Go to APIs overview under APIs.
>
> In API manager, select Credentials on the left bar, then select OAuth
> consent screen. Change the name in the field under Product name shown
> to users and then click on Save. We will suspend your Cloud project in
> 3 days unless you correct the problem. Please submit an appeal if you
> have any questions. Please note that you should be logged in as the
> project owner to access the appeals page. For more help on submitting
> an appeal or to learn more about the process check the  Policy
> Violation FAQ. Please take a moment to review the Google API Services:
> User Data Policy, the Google API Terms of Service, the Google Cloud
> Terms of Service and the applicable Terms of Service for the specific
> Google API you are using so that you do not violate our terms and
> policies in the future.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about managing a business relationship, communicating between the question OP and a third party, and/or dealing with a legal issue. In other words, it's not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic]. You might be able to get help from the Customer Service for the company you are interfacing with. If you want an interpretation of legal requirements, it might be appropriate to ask on [law.se].

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously a naming issue regarding something in the google product range.
You Should be able to re-name your project to solve this.

If not, try a Google forum or help pages.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are having is that Google does not allow you to use a Google product name as the name of your in your application.  Users can become confused and assume your third party application was created by them.

**How to fix it:**

Go to [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) find the credentials screen.  Click on the Oauth consent screen tab at the top rename your application.

[image]

Note: If you don't do this google is going to shut down your application they are very picky about this.